When value = X, I want a different column to go up by 1 integer in R
I am working with a large amount of sports event data, while it is obvious from context that event X happens in match 1 and event Y happens in match 2, unfortunately there is no column stating this occurs in match 1 etc. This is an issue for the downstream analysis I want to do, and would be much easier if I could use group_by(match_number).
I have timestamp data that resets to 0 for every new match so that I can use this to create a new column using mutate(ifelse(timestamp == 0, ???))
In the end I would like something like this:



timestamp(mins)
event
match_number




0
event 1
1


34.5
event 2
1


90
event 3
1


0
event 1
2


60.4
event 2
2


90
event 3
2


0
event 1
3


54.3
event 2
3


90
event 3
3



I thought about using mutate(ifelse()) but am coming up blank of how to go about the rest of the command and I have been unable to find a non-python thread on the topic. Any help would be appreciated.

match_number = cumsum(timestamp == 0)?
